'spark.jars.packages' not working as expected in AWS Glue and Spark
I want to use some Maven repository JAR files in my Spark session so I am creating the session with 'spark.jars.packages' which would automatically download the JARs. This is not working as expected as I am having the Session config correctly configured (('spark.jars.packages', 'net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.13.6,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.9.0-spark_3.1'),).
But I still have the error: "Failed to find data source: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html" which would be solved if I upload the JARs manually.
I am using Glue v4.
If I update the JARs manually it is working I need them to download automatically.
What can I try next?

Glue doesn't allow dynamic loading of packages using "spark.jars.packages".
To add dependencies need to use the magics %additional_python_modules and %extra_jars In the case of Python you can reference directly to pip modules but in the case of the jars, it doesn't accept maven coordinates, unfortunately, you need to get the jars, put then on s3 and then reference then using %extra_jars.

The following code works for me. Copy this code in your script and rerun. Mostly issue would be with maven coordinates not provided correctly.
Example code :
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

packages_so = 'net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.13.6,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.9.0-spark_3.1'
repository = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", packages_so) \
    .config("spark.jars.repositories", repository) \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


Hi, thanks for the help. It keeps without working. I'm creating the Spark session like this. Any idea?
`packages_so = 'net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.13.6,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.9.0-spark_3.1'
spark = SparkSession 
.builder 
.config("spark.jars.packages", packages_so) 
.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)`

What is the error?

Failed to find data source: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:574)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:675)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:725)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:864)

I updated the answer to provide .config("spark.jars.repositories", repository) from where it can download the packages.

Same error sir.
Failed to find data source: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.
packages_so = ... repository = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" sparkConf = (     SparkConf()     .setAppName("DHGlueJob")     .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")     .set("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false")     .set("spark.jars.packages", packages_so)     .set("spark.jars.repositories", repository) ) glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)) spark = glueContext.spark_session

Read this doc. It seems there is a version mismatch of scala and spark. Also use a compatible version of jdbc driver.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-install
One troubleshoot mechanism is to remove the offending package and see if you are able to download other packages.

One troubleshoot mechanism is to remove the offending package and see if you are able to download other packages. --> How i can check if other packages are downloaded? Does it creates any logs? Or how?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-view.html

I know how to see the logs jeje my question if there should be kind of downloading logs whenever the session is created?

Found this:
Glue doesn't allow dynamic loading of packages using "spark.jars.packages".
To add dependencies need to use the magics %additional_python_modules and %extra_jars
In the case of Python you can reference directly to pip modules but in the case of the jars, it doesn't accept maven coordinates, unfortunately, you need to get the jars, put then on s3 and then reference then using %extra_jars.
What do you think? How did you manage it to work...?
